# How to have a custom type behave as a String with QueryDSL

Tags: java, querydsl, mongodb-java

I am trying to use a custom type with QueryDSL, something like this:

```
public class Email implements Comparable<Email> {
    public String name;
    public String domain;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Email o) {
        return toString().compareTo(o.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "@" + domain;
    }
}
```

I then have a QueryDSL entity that uses this custom type:

```
@Entity
public class Record {
    public Email email;
    public String text;
}
```

I can then build Queries like this:

```
BooleanExpression withEmail(Email email)
{
    QRecord Q = QRecord.record;
    BooleanExpression pred = Q.email.eq(email);
    return pred;
}
```

However, when using `MongodbSerializer`, the query ends up setting the `Email` type in a mongo `DBObject`, and later I get an exception from the mongo driver saying that `Email` cannot be serialized.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: json can't serialize type : class Email
```

If I annotated by `email` field in my `Record` like this:

```
@Entity
public class Record {
    @QueryType(PropertyType.STRING)
    public Email email;
    public String text;
}
```

Then it starts working - although I have to manipulate the email with a email as strings in my query constructions instead of the email objects themselves, ex. `QRecord.record.email.eq(myEmail.toString())` instead of simply `QRecord.record.email.eq(myEmail)` like before.

My issue with this solution is that anyone using the `Email` object has to know that they should annotate it when embedding it inside another object.

Question: is there a way to annotate the `Email` class in such a way that it will always be serialized as a string entity - or is there a better way to achieve this altogether?

Comment: implement serializable?

Comment: That doesn't work, the `Email` object gets inserted in a `BasicDBObject` and the mongo driver only support a small subset of types in `DBObject`s which afaik don't include custom types.  The problem is that `Email` should not get inserted as is into a `BasicDBObject` in the first place.

Comment: If you want to insert and retrieve Email objects into MongoDB use Codec API. Checkout http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/codecs/